# How should I containerize my python scripts with shared resources?

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes

I'm learning about Docker containers for Kubernetes.  But I'm running into some confusion.
Currently, I structure my files this way:

```
project
  -some.ini
  -common.py
  -context1.py
  -context2.py
```

The context.py scripts import common.py and some.ini at runtime.  But this setup isn't good for Docker, you want these to be split...

```
project
  context1
    -some.ini
    -common.py
    -context1.py
    -Dockerfile
    -requirements.txt

  context2
    -some.ini
    -common.py
    -context2.py
    -Dockerfile
    -requirements.txt
```

this is what I'm doing right now.  But this is a terrible structure!  I want to reuse common.py, and other packages.

I thought I would try this :

```
project
   common.py
   some.ini
   -context1
     run1.py
   -context2
     run2.py
```

But Python3 doesn't support relative imports.  There are work arounds but what I really want to know is if there is a preferred way to do this.

Is there a suggested structure for what I'm trying to do?  What's the best way to balance containerizing and reusing resources?

Thanks

Comment: Typically individual Python files aren't that large; is there any reason to not just keep all of these files in the same image?

Comment: my top level scripts are very contextual, they're search queries, and I just don't want to risk having a bunch of versions of the same code for each query file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a `docker-compose.yml` file?  I'm not sure if I understand the question, but it seems like you are trying to combine two seperate sevices with common resources?

```
myapp/
  - context1
    - some.ini
    - common.py
    - context1.py
    - requirements.txt
    - Dockerfile
  - context2
    - some.ini
    - common.py
    - context2.py
    - requirements.txt
    - Dockerfile
  - docker-compose.yml
```

Then your `docker-compose.yml` file can look something like:

```
version: '3'

services:
  context1:
    build: './context1'
  context2:
    build: './context2'
```

Comment: You know what, I think this is exactly what I'm supposed to do, lol.  I knew there was a way.  I will try this out.  Thank you.

Comment: @qwerty10110 awesome, yeah its pretty cool, you can basically microservice out everything and even persist state between all your services.  makes deploying a lot simpler.  here are the docks on Docker compose:  https://docs.docker.com/compose/